# Word "EditPaste" command is broken

Tags: microsoft-word, copy-paste, microsoft-word-2016

I have run into a weird problem in Microsoft Word, where the Paste command (`EditPaste`) stopped working.

The clipboard in general works, I can copy text, and I can also use other paste commands in Paste Special, but the basic Paste doesn't do anything. This is for both pressing the hotkey Ctrl+V and the ribbon button.

There is a similar paste command, `EditPaste2` with the same description in english (a slightly different description in german) that works fine and I am using that as a workaround.

The problem is only in Word, other Office programs like Excel and Powerpoint work fine. I can not link the failure to a particular event like and update or similar.

Does someone have an idea what could cause this behavior and how I can fix it?

The Word version is: Microsoft Word 2016 MSO (16.0.12730.20252) 64-bit

There are copy paste settings as follows:
[image]

Comment: Did you recently install any addins to ms word?

Comment: @Sanu_012 Damn, so I actually first went into the options to disable all addins (none were shown as active). Then restarted Word and the problem was still there, hence this question. Now I checked again and apparently disabling the addin didn't work. When I manually deleted the related dotm, the paste function works again. Thanks, my bad, I'm deleting the question because of trivial cause...

Comment: I think this question need not be deleted. Keep it as it is for future references. So, seems like dotm was interfering with the shortcut :)

Comment: True as well, @Sanu_012. I described my fix in the answer. Cheers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As suggested by Sanu_012 in the comments I double-checked the addins.

Doing so I found, that an addin of the MathType software (MathType Commands 6 For Word 2016.dotm) was still enabled. I tried disabling it by `Manage: Word Add-ins` > Unchecking it in the `Global Templates` list and clicking OK. After doing so, it no longer appears in the `Active Application Add-ins` list, however when Word is restarted the addin is again loaded.

To permanently disable it, I deleted the whole Template from the path given in the Addin list and restarted Word.

Afterwards, the Paste command worked again.